# Getting the $Max value within a nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm attempting to extract the highest value from an child Array within Object, that is within a parent Array - in a single MongoDB document.

The child Array is called `data` contained within the `list` parent Array, where i'm trying to extract the highest `number`, when compared to the rest of the same values.

I've tried using `$Group` and `$max` (example below) among other things - however not getting much success.  - I am getting an array returned with all the number values: `[2,3]`

How do I search through the `list` Array and `data` Array to return the highest `number`?

Expected Output for the below example: `{output: 3}`

Example in MongoPlayground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/qw9Kz_WVYiS

**Mongo DB Setup and Documents**

```
db={
  "groups": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("602ed22af42c404096407dda"),
      "groupName": "Name"
    }
  ],
  "inventory": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("602ed22af42c404096407ddc"),
      "linkedGroup": ObjectId("602ed22af42c404096407dda"),
      "list": [
        {
          "_id": ObjectId("602eeb0621a11045638b7082"),
          "data": {
            "number": 2
          },
          
        },
        {
          "_id": ObjectId("602eec75c37147459ed7b12c"),
          "data": {
            "number": 3
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Query**

```
db.groups.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "inventory",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "linkedGroup",
      "as": "inventory_links"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: 1,
      output: {
        $max: "$inventory_links.list.data.number"
      },
      
    },
    
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$reduce` to find the maximum. With your query, you can add other stages,

```
{
    $addFields: {
      _id: 1,
      inventory_links: {"$arrayElemAt": ["$inventory_links",0]}
    }
},
{
    $project: {
      output: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$inventory_links.list",
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {$gte: [ "$$this.data.number","$$value"]},
              "$$this.data.number",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kJCIO0I0W4J)**